# Make function for concatenate in R

Tags: r, function, concatenation

I have a dataframe like:

```
Dis                           Area 
NAGAR,SANGANER                NAGAR,PRATAP NAGAR,SANGANER
NAGAR                         NAGAR,SODALA,BHANDARI
JHUNJHUNUN,BARI               BARI
```

Splitting the data using the sep ","

New Dataframe(df1) looks like the below:

```
Dis        Dis1        Area  Area1  Area2  Area3
NAGAR      SANGANER    NAGAR PRATAP NAGAR SANGANER
NAGAR                  NAGAR SODALA BHANDARI
JHUNJHUNUN  BARI       BARI
```

Now, I want to concatenate Dis with Area and other respectively using sep "|". Similarly with Dis1
dataframe will look like:(Desirable output)

```
Dis|Area         Dis1|Area        Dis|Area1           Dis1|Area1
NAGAR|NAGAR      SANGANER|NAGAR   NAGAR|PRATAP NAGAR  SANGANER|PRATAP NAGAR
NAGAR|NAGAR      |NAGAR           NAGAR|SODALA        |SODALA
JHUNJHUNUN|BARI  BARI|BARI        JHUNJHUNUN|         BARI|
```

and so on....

How to make a function for this.
For all the columns post split, it automatically concatenate them with other columns.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what your starting data looks like, or final output (see comment above). However, this might be something helpful in moving forward.

It looks like you already have split your comma-separated columns. You can concatenate columns from "Dis" and "Area" by creating a data frame of column names that need to be combined.

You can then use `expand.grid` to create a combination of "Dis" columns and "Area" columns. This could also be generalized by using the column names themselves (starting with "Dis" or "Area") if desired.

The `sapply` statement will go through these combination of column name pairs and concatenate the corresponding strings together.

**Edit:** A unique reference `id` is added for each row.

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2,3),
  Dis = c("NAGAR,SANGANER", "NAGAR", "JHUNJHUNUN,BARI"),
  Area = c("NAGAR,PRATAP NAGAR,SANGANER", "NAGAR,SODALA,BHANDARI", "BARI"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

df2 <- df %>%
  separate(Dis, into = paste0('Dis', 1:3), sep = ',') %>%
  separate(Area, into = paste0('Area', 1:3), sep = ',')

df2[is.na(df2)] <- ""

exp_cols <- expand.grid(names(df2)[2:4], names(df2)[5:7])

df_final <- cbind(df2$id, as.data.frame(sapply(1:nrow(exp_cols), function(x){
  do.call(paste, c(df2[, as.character(unlist(exp_cols[x,]))], sep=" | "))
})))

names(df_final) <- c("id", paste(exp_cols[,1], exp_cols[,2], sep = "_"))
```

**Output**

```
  id        Dis1_Area1       Dis2_Area1 Dis3_Area1           Dis1_Area2              Dis2_Area2      Dis3_Area2       Dis1_Area3          Dis2_Area3  Dis3_Area3
1  1     NAGAR | NAGAR SANGANER | NAGAR    | NAGAR NAGAR | PRATAP NAGAR SANGANER | PRATAP NAGAR  | PRATAP NAGAR NAGAR | SANGANER SANGANER | SANGANER  | SANGANER
2  2     NAGAR | NAGAR          | NAGAR    | NAGAR       NAGAR | SODALA                | SODALA        | SODALA NAGAR | BHANDARI          | BHANDARI  | BHANDARI
3  3 JHUNJHUNUN | BARI      BARI | BARI     | BARI        JHUNJHUNUN |                  BARI |               |     JHUNJHUNUN |              BARI |           |
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It is quite helpful. Now, if I say I have ref Id, which should be there at the start of the data but doesn't need to concatenate, how I can approach that.

Comment: @SiddhiKharkia An `id` is added for each row, see edited answer.

Comment: Thankyou so much :)

Comment: Glad to hear this helped. Feel free to [accept or upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if appropriate.